# GString inside a Gstring in gradle/groovy

Tags: gradle, groovy

I need to use a variable as a part of a string that will be used to address another variable in a gstring.
In syntesys, what I'd like to do is: `${${it}_checkout}`

The whole code line would be:
`def checkouts = repos.collect{"${it} = ${${it}_checkout} "}`

With `repos` being a list of repositories to checkout.
Each repo has an property called `<repo>_checkout`.

For instance, if I have two repos, called `foo` and `bar`, I'll have two variables called `foo_checkout` and `bar_checkout`, containing the branches to be checkouted.
I'm trying to construct the following string: "foo=$foo_checkout bar=$bar_checkout".
That will be translated to "foo=master bar=dev"

Is there a way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeh, just do:

```
def checkouts = repos.collect{ "$it = ${it}_checkout" }
```

Or, depending on how you declare your properties, you can do:

```
root_checkout = 'woo'
repo_checkout = 'yay'

['root', 'repo'].collect { r -> "$r = ${getProperty(r + '_checkout')}" }
```

Comment: The thing is that I need the value of the variable that would be called ${it}_checkout.  For instance, if I have a repo named `foo`, I'll have a variable called `foo_checkout` containg the branch to checkout. I'll update the question to avoid confusion

Comment: @PedroWitzel Updated answer, hope it's closer?